# How can I save code in an apply loop in R?

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to use R to generate code, both to show my collegues 'what is happening' in the background (and to be able to debug code more easily) and to be able to adjust code in specific cases.

My specific case is far more elaborate, but hopefully this example makes clear what I want:

```
tables <- function(df,vars=all_of(var_list), weight=1){
    
  table_list <-   lapply({{vars}}, function(x){
      
      df %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = all_of(x), names_to = "question", values_to = "answer") %>% 
        group_by(question,answer) %>%
        summarise(n = sum(weight)) %>% 
        mutate(percentage = (n / sum(n)*100)) %>%
        ungroup()
  }
    )
    
  
  
  return(table_list)

}
```

Running `tables(df=spss_data,vars = all_of(c("q3","q6")), weight = 1)` returns a list of dataframes, which is what I want. What i would like is to also save the code that is used for every variable. For example:

```
spss_data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = q3, names_to = "question", values_to = "answer") %>% 
  group_by(question,answer) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(weight)) %>% 
  mutate(percentage = (n / sum(n)*100)) %>%
  ungroup() 

and  

spss_data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = q6, names_to = "question", values_to = "answer") %>% 
  group_by(question,answer) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(weight)) %>% 
  mutate(percentage = (n / sum(n)*100)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This code can be stored in a list or vector to be saved later. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you come from a SAS background by chance? Programming in SAS is mostly done though macros where this type of request would make sense. R is a functional programming language which be haves differently. It doesn't really build code chunks, it calls and executes functions. Those "desired" commands you write are never actually run like that in R. You could use R to build those expressions, but that would be different than what is actually being run, though logically they produce the same output.

Comment: I come from a spss background. For me, just using the output would suffice, but by saving the code as well, I could be more transparant to others in what is happening in  the background. In my complete code there are more conditions, so showing others what code is being run when would give them more insight.

Comment: But the code you've shown is not what's actually being run.; it's a human readable interpretation of what's being run. If you wanted to generate that output, you could build strings that look like R code. But there's not a built-in way to generate that output.

Comment: I just tried expression() which enables me to save the code in an object, but it only works for 'literal' code, and doesn't display the variables used in the loop

Comment: You can use `bquote()` to substitute values into an expression. For example `bquote(spss_data %>% pivot_longer(cols = .(as.symbol(x)), names_to = "question", values_to = "answer"))`

Answer (score -2):

R Markdown is an authoring format that enables easy creation of dynamic documents, presentations, and reports from R. It combines the core syntax of markdown (an easy-to-write plain text format) with embedded R code chunks that are run so their output can be included in the final document. R Markdown documents are fully reproducible (they can be automatically regenerated whenever underlying R code or data changes). See a concise introduction at https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/205368677-R-Markdown-Dynamic-Documents-for-R